# select the first radio button by default in lightning:datatable aura component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, aura, lightning-datatable

I am using lightning:datatable aura component. I am producing radio buttons on every row. I am also able to select only one radio button. The query is I want the first row (radio button) to be selected by default, every time the table is loaded. I have tried using selected-rows attribute, but it isn't working for me. I think it only works for checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Amending the basic table example from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/example and this works:

```html
<!-- basic.html -->

<template>
    <div style="height: 300px;">
        <lightning-datatable
                key-field="id"
                data={data}
                columns={columns}
                max-row-selection="1"
                selected-rows={selectedRows}>
        </lightning-datatable>
    </div>    
</template>
```

```js
// basic.js

import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import fetchDataHelper from './fetchDataHelper';

const columns = [
    { label: 'Label', fieldName: 'name' },
    { label: 'Website', fieldName: 'website', type: 'url' },
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'phone', type: 'phone' },
    { label: 'Balance', fieldName: 'amount', type: 'currency' },
    { label: 'CloseAt', fieldName: 'closeAt', type: 'date' },
];

export default class BasicDatatable extends LightningElement {
    data = [];
    columns = columns;

    @track selectedRows;

    // eslint-disable-next-line @lwc/lwc/no-async-await
    async connectedCallback() {
        const data = await fetchDataHelper({ amountOfRecords: 100 });
        this.data = data;
        this.selectedRows = data.length > 0 ? [data[0].id] : [];
    }
}
```

```js
// dataFetchHelper.js

const recordMetadata = {
    name: 'name',
    email: 'email',
    website: 'url',
    amount: 'currency',
    phone: 'phoneNumber',
    closeAt: 'dateInFuture',
};

export default function fetchDataHelper({ amountOfRecords }) {
    return fetch('https://data-faker.herokuapp.com/collection', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            amountOfRecords,
            recordMetadata,
        }),
    }).then(response => response.json());
}
```

[image]